# Get username from windows based network trhough java web application

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, intranet

I'm developing a java web application using Spring MVC.
This application will be accessed by users via browsers like IE and Chrome.
It will be available only for users from my windows based network company (intranet).
Is there a way of retrieve information from user that made a request to my web application from his client, like username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Waffle](https://github.com/dblock/waffle) authentication framework

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need something like this, but my application is deployed in a unix envoironment and Waffle does not work in such case.

Comment: You hadn't mentioned that before...  There is also Spring Kerberos but I have not used it directly.